# Redhat disable CPU throttling

Tags: cpu, rhel-6, throttling

How can I disable CPU throttling?

 I need this done in order to properly install atlas. I have checked alot of similar questions on google as well as here on superuser and didn't find a solution.

Using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)`

Here's my CPU info

```
[root@tpdb05 stage]# cat /proc/acpi/processor/CPU0/info
processor id:            0
acpi id:                 0
bus mastering control:   no
power management:        no
throttling control:      yes
limit interface:         yes


[root@tpdb05 stage]# cat /proc/acpi/processor/CPU1/info
processor id:            1
acpi id:                 1
bus mastering control:   no
power management:        no
throttling control:      yes
limit interface:         yes
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to find answer here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling

Comment: Why do you need to disable throttling? Is it really a requirement for atlas?

Comment: Thanks @Nikolai, I found out our servers are only throttling when they are overheating.!

Comment: @krzyk Yes, it is. Check [this link](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~nmv/2013/07/09/for-faster-r-use-openblas-instead-better-than-atlas-trivial-to-switch-to-on-ubuntu/#comment-769) for more information!

Answer (score 4):

The throttling control is managed by the *cpuspeed daemon* on RedHat 6.5

You can stop the daemon:

```
service cpuspeed stop
```

This is not true that servers are only throttling when they are overheating,
Cpu scaling change the cpu frequency by the server's workload, by default to minimum while the cpu is idle and to maximum when the there is a heavy workload.
This parameter called *governor* and it can be changed.
More information can be found at [RedHat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Power_Management_Guide/cpufreq_governors.html).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that in my company it is throttled at 3333hz (if I remember correctl). Unless certain conditions (like overheating) change this. (I think this is the way it works, I didn't do in-depth research about it). But your solution looks great, thank you!

Comment: I forgot to add in, the servers are run on a virtual machine, maybe this affects it

Comment: That should not happen on Virtual servers because the module is not been loaded to the kernel.